# Ajax request to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I'm using ajax to pull some data from my database every 10 sec.

My question will this effect my mysql database .. will it slow down my site or crypt my database

Please let me know if it is good idea to send request to my database every few sec to refresh page.

I try top pull banners and refreshing every few sec.

thanks

Comment: I hope you're not selling ads on a per-impression basis...

Comment: usually AJAX is used to update part of a page. Consider only replacing the contents of a div with each AJAX call instead of refreshing the entire page content.

Answer (score 2):

Any DBMS is capable of responding to a query every 10 seconds. Most DBMSes can handle hundreds of requests per second even on commodity hardware.

Nevertheless, it all depends on the complexity of your query. Most importantly, you need to make sure that your query is able to use an index.

On the other hand, there is nothing stopping you from adding a simple caching layer between your application and your database, such that the info is returned from the cache unless an update to the database invalidates the cache.

Comment: I'd note that while a DBMS is certainly capable of a query every ten seconds, if you get a couple thousand concurrent visitors with the page open you may run into trouble (and on the web server end of things, too).